# Javascript unlink upon clicking delete

Tags: javascript, loops, codeigniter, filepath, unlink

Hello how do you unlink a folder file in a loop upon clicking each delete button? It's only unlinking the first file. thanks

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-8">
  <label>Files:</label>
  
  <?php

  $this->load->helper('directory');
  $map = directory_map($results['bid_folderpath']);
  $i = 0;
  $path = $results['bid_folderpath']."/".$map[$i];

                    
  while (isset($map[$i]))
  {
      // $map = directory_map($results['bid_folderpath']);

  echo "<p id='test'>".$map[$i]."<input type='button' id ='delete_test' name ='delete_file' onClick='.unlink($path).' value='Delete'></p>";
      $i = $i+1;
      echo $path;
  }

  ?>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#delete_test").click(function(){
    $("#test").remove();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript cannot execute PHP code.

Comment: read up about Ajax, for example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX or here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It's unlinking the file before you even send that html to the page from server

Comment: anyone knows how?